# How to extract the first item in a set of dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop

Please see the screenshot...

I'm trying to create another column pulling the first element of the column 'genre' (i.e. Animation for the first one, Adventure for the second one, Romance for the third one and so on...)

Could anyone please help?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the data from the dictionary or from the dataframe. In this code, I convert the column to a list before splitting.

```
import pandas as pd


### from dictionary

dd = { 'genres':[
       [{'id':16,'name':'Animation'},{'id':26,'name':'ChicFlick'}],
       [{'id':12,'name':'Adventure'},{'id':22,'name':'Horror'}],
       [{'id':18,'name':'Romance'},{'id':28,'name':'Crime'}],
       ]}
       
dd['genres2'] = [x[0]['name'] for x in dd['genres']]

print(dd)


### from dataframe

dd = { 'genres':[
       [{'id':16,'name':'Animation'},{'id':26,'name':'ChicFlick'}],
       [{'id':12,'name':'Adventure'},{'id':22,'name':'Horror'}],
       [{'id':18,'name':'Romance'},{'id':28,'name':'Crime'}],
       ]}
       
df = pd.DataFrame(dd)

df['genres2'] = [x[0]['name'] for x in df['genres'].to_list()]

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Output

```
{'genres': 
     [[{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 26, 'name': 'ChicFlick'}], 
     [{'id': 12, 'name': 'Adventure'}, {'id': 22, 'name': 'Horror'}], 
     [{'id': 18, 'name': 'Romance'}, {'id': 28, 'name': 'Crime'}]], 
 'genres2': ['Animation', 'Adventure', 'Romance']}

                                                             genres    genres2
 [{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 26, 'name': 'ChicFlick'}]  Animation
    [{'id': 12, 'name': 'Adventure'}, {'id': 22, 'name': 'Horror'}]  Adventure
       [{'id': 18, 'name': 'Romance'}, {'id': 28, 'name': 'Crime'}]    Romance
```